# Is my MacBook hacked?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-silicon, ventura, hacking

This message keeps popping up on my MacBook
[image: screenshot of Login Items]
The guy I bought this MacBook from helped me download some apps (e.g. Microsoft Office) using his hard drive. Could it be that he maybe somehow also added some kind of malware to my MacBook?

I haven't noticed anything else that's weird, only this, but it's freaking me out.

[image: screenshot of macOS alert 'Background Items Added']

Comment: AFAIK, bash shouldn't be from an unidentified developer. You can unselect it, but you may also want to check Activity Monitor to see what other processes are running.

Comment: ive tried disabling it, but it enables again whenever i reboot @AlexIxeras. also i read somewhere else about activity monitor too, but i dont know what to look for

Comment: You could try a virus scanner, free or paid.

Comment: If you click on the little i "info" button, what happens? Normally it takes you to the process in the Finder. It's likely that something is running a shell script in the background. but that's not necessarily indicative of malware. As said, use something like Malwarebytes to check for malware. But 99% of "Have I been hacked" questions are answered "No."

Comment: "The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$ " this is what the terminal window said @benwiggy. so im guessing its alright..? 

Comment: Is that what happened when you click on the i ? It brought up a Terminal window?

Comment: @benwiggy It it works the same as it does for me, it opens a Finder window showing the content of `/bin`, with `bash` selected. I haven't been able to figure out what the entry is actually related to (but then I didn't put a lot of time into it).

Comment: it opened a finder window with a bunch of terminal files in it, namely, 'cat', 'chmod', 'kill', 'hostname', 'bash' etc. i clicked bash and it opened a terminal window that said that^ @benwiggy

Comment: Well, if you selected (or started) `bash` then you start a Terminal window with the bash shell selected, and since `zsh` is now the Apple default shell you get the above message. You could try to just disable the bash entry in Login Items, restart and see if that has an adverse effect, ie. something isn't working as expected. Alternatively, while this is running take a look at Activity Monitor, hit Cmd-F and search for bash to see if it is running.